# Use EditText for TextView

Tags: android

I have a question, i want to create a random sentense. At my first activity i have 4 EditText (for the name of player).

I have make the code for generate a random sentense but i didn't know how add the value of EditText.

MainActivity : 4 EditText
RandomActivity : Show somes sentenses from my String.

I want make a sentense like : [EDITTEXT1] WORD WORD WORD [EDITEXT2]

Can you try to explain me how do ? Thank you !

RandomActivity :

```
 Resources res = getResources();

        myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.phrases);

        String q = myString[rgenerator.nextInt(myString.length)];

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(q);
```

My XML File for sentenses

```
<string-array name="phrases"> // name of the string array
    <item>Phrase 1</item> // items
    <item>Phrase 2</item>
    <item>Phrase 3</item>
    <item>Phrase 4</item>
</string-array>
```

My XML for EditText

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text="Joueur 1"
        android:textColor="#FFF"

        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
        android:autoText="true"
        android:editable="true"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:minWidth="200dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Joueur 2"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Joueur 3"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="Joueur 4"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText3" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 private String generateString() {
    Context context;
    String [] phrases = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.phrases);
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    return stringBuilder
            .append(editeText.getText().toString())
            .append(phrases[0])
            .append(phrases[1])
            .append(editeText2.getText().toString())
            .toString();
}
```

If textView has vale "**Apple**", textView 2 has value "**Orange**"
This method will get you a string that says "**Hello phrase1 phrase2 Orange**".

So using string builder you can use append() like I have done above you can add append your string.